# How to call a webservice or url from spring 3.x

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

I really don't know how to proceed with this in Spring.

I have an URL `https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice.php?form=2` which I have to call with some parameters and consume the result.

How can I do it with Spring ?

Comment: It's not something you do specifically in Spring. Use any http client that Java has available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in the case of java libs one should know whether the request is post or get etc. my case is different I don't know the requesting method type. it is a payment gateway url. Hope I make sense and I am not wrong too :)

Comment: If you don't know the http method, how are you going to send an http request?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis :) thanks for the point out, the requesting method type is `POST`. I am trying to find the way to call this using the below answer provided by @kocko.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), which supports mashalling, unmarshalling, variable resolution, etc.

For example, you have to do something similar to this:

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("hotel", "42");
vars.put("booking", "21");
String result = 
    restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", String.class, vars);
```

More info:

- [REST in Spring3](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/)

Comment: @kocko, it was nice, I found that my web service calling method type is `post`